# Can you use high tier wings with other wings in the social slot?

Tags: terraria

I want to use the duke fishron wings. However I enjoy the appearance of the ghost wings. Would it be possible to have ghost wings in the social slot but have the effect the fishron wings offer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Normally, wings override items in the social slot, e.g. capes, but the wings in the social slot will be the ones that appear on your character (without providing any stats).

Comment: I use the shroomite hoverboard because super-fast horizontal travel is amazing. But, I despise how it looks, so I put the flame wings in the social slot. I'm REALLY glad I'm able to take the functionality of one pair of wings and the looks of another.